# c# Windows Form Application adding data to tables with relationship

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, linq

I'm new to c# Windows Form Application and I'm having a problem in adding/inserting data to SQL DB that has relationship between tables.
My question is, Will the relation between the tables function in C# Windows Form Application?

This is how my DB looks

[image: This is how my DB looks]

I'm looking for a way to add data to the Article table and Body table where Artcle.body_id will pupolate accordingly. The same as MVC.
Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the code now. Hope this will help others in the future.

```
   private void buttonCreateSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Body body = new Body
        {
            body_content = richTextBoxBody.Text
        };

        tnDBase.AddToBodies(body);
        tnDBase.SaveChanges();

        var genid = tnDBase.Genres.Single(g => g.genre_name == comboBoxGenre.Text);

        Article article = new Article()
        {
            article_name = textBoxTitle.Text,
            genre_id = genid.genre_id,
            status_id = 3,
            body_id = body.body_id
        };

        tnDBase.AddToArticles(article);
        tnDBase.SaveChanges();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom method to update or insert the values.

Comment: I have no problems in getting data from the DB. It's the adding/inserting data that i have a problem. The i have to update is 'Article.status_id = 2; DBname.SaveChanges();'

Comment: Can you please include the query which you are using for inserting the data.

Comment: `Article article = new Article()
            {
                article_name = textBoxTitle.Text
            }; DBname.SaveChanges();`

Comment: What is in function DBname.SaveChanges()...??
can you provide the content.

Comment: DBname.SaveChanges(); is use for saving the changes in the Database

Comment: Did you define this method or its the one predefined.
And what do you actually want to insert...correct me if I am wrong - "Update Article.status_id = 2 where article_name = textBoxTitle.Text"

Comment: predefined. I can actually insert data using the code above but Article.body_id remains null. It won't change to the body_id under Body table.

Comment: Look body_id is a foreign key. It will remain null unless you provide a Article.body_id. If it is Null it will point to corresponding record in body table. Are you adding a value to Article.body_id? Please specify your code clearly. According to above code you are just adding article name.

Comment: I dont think you are getting me. I am looking for a way to make it work like MVC where I add a new data for Article and Body. In MVC the Article.body_id is populated automatically which is the same as Body.body_id. I don't have a code for my Winform to do this.